# Keycloak CLI: Creating an Identity Provider Mapper

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm trying to create a IDP provider mapper using the keycloak CLI similar to this
[image: Mapper I want to create]

The examples in the [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#adding-mappers) are all for *storage* mappers.

I've tried

```
kcadm.sh create components -r my-realm -s name=my-mapper-name -s providerId=oidc-hardcoded-role-idp-mapper -s providerType=org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityProviderMapper -s parentId=<parent id> -s 'config.role=["ROLE_MY_ROLE"]'
```

But that fails with the error

```
14:45:26,325 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-7) Uncaught server error: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.keycloak.broker.provider.HardcodedRoleMapper cannot be cast to class org.keycloak.component.ComponentFactory (org.keycloak.broker.provider.HardcodedRoleMapper is in unnamed module of loader 'org.keycloak.keycloak-services@9.0.0' @1dd6d570; org.keycloak.component.ComponentFactory is in unnamed module of loader 'org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi@9.0.0' @8467851)
```

Since unlike `HardcodedLDAPRoleStorageMapperFactory` it doesn't extend `ComponentFactory`.

Is it possible to do this with the keycloak CLI?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to called as follows:

```
./kcadm.sh create identity-provider/instances/<IDP_name>/mappers \ 
          -r <REALM_NAME> \
          -s name=<MAPPER_NAME> \
          -s identityProviderAlias=<IDP_ALIAS> \ 
          -s identityProviderMapper=oidc-hardcoded-role-idp-mapper \
          -s config.role=<ROLE_NAME>
```

For easy copy & paste:

```
./kcadm.sh create identity-provider/instances/<IDP_name>/mappers  -r <REALM_NAME> -s name=<MAPPER_NAME> -s identityProviderAlias=<IDP_ALIAS> -s identityProviderMapper=oidc-hardcoded-role-idp-mapper -s config.role=<ROLE_NAME>
```

The field `identityProviderMapper` is the `Mapper Type`, which in your case will be `oidc-hardcoded-role-idp-mapper`.